# GMM fit best model

Tags: python

There is a part in a Gaussian Mixture Model (GMM) fit which I dont understand it. I would be happy to have your suggestions:

```
 g  = GMM(3, n_iter=1000, verbose=True, random_state=3)
 g.fit(WORK)

 np.random.seed(1)
 X = g.sample(1000)

 # fit models with 1-10 components
 N = np.arange(1, 11)
 models = [None for i in range(len(N))]

 for i in range(len(N)):
    models[i] = GMM(N[i]).fit(X)
```

Comment: where do you import GMM from?

Comment: from sklearn.mixture import GMM

Comment: What don't you understand?

Comment: models = [None for i in range(len(N))]

Comment: It is initializing a list of length `len(N)` with `None` values everywhere. Look at 'list comprehensions'. Each `None` is ultimately supposed to be replaced by the result of a fit.

Answer (score 0):

It is generating a list `models` of fits with the assumption that there are respectively i=1,2,...,10 components in the mixture, probably with the intent to select the best model among them.

Answer (score 0):

Could somebody point to why do we create a GMM with 3 components from WORK,
and then draw samples from the GMM for a better model

I would have  simplified this this to,

```
np.random.seed(1) #will ensure reproducibiity
# fit models with 1-10 components
N = np.arange(1, 11)
models = [None for i in range(len(N))]

#find the model with  minimum aic score
min_aic = np.inf
model_index_with_min_aic = -1
for i in range(len(N)):
    models[i] = GMM(N[i], n_iter=1000).fit(WORK)
    aic = models[i[.aic(WORK)
    if aic < min_aic:
        model_index_with_min_aic = i
        min_aic = aic
```

Answer (score 0):

GMM basically, crate a 'model' for each train sample, so if you have 10 train samples you probably also get 10 models for each of it.

And if you want to test the model you will also need to call each model created by GMM, so it would be like [1:1] x N times